# Cannot update during an existing state transition when fetching counts

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to fetch post likes, and pass it as a prop to redux.

So i can use it like

`myLikes={this.props.myLikes}` which renders Likes 6  or whatever the count number is

```
{this.getLikes(post.Likes)} // retrieves like counts
```

However i get this warning

> Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within
>   `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and
>   state.

My objective is to retrieve likes and map it back to its respected post.

What approach should i use, or am i somewhere in the ballpark ? Cause of now all im getting duplicate values like this

[Duplicate values shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGOXQ.png)

here is the code

**PostList.js**

```
    getLikes = (count) =>  {

        this.props.getCount(count)      

    }
    render(){
        const {posts} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (

                    <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                             {this.getLikes(post.Likes)}
                    {/* {...post} prevents us from writing all of the properties out */}
                        <PostItem  
                             myLikes={this.props.myLikes}                 
                             myTitle={this.state.title} 
                             editChange={this.onChange} 
                             editForm={this.formEditing} 
                             isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} 
                             removePost={this.removePost} 
                             {...post} 
                        />
                    </Paper>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    myLikes: state.post.likes
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostList);
```

**Actions.js**

```
export const getCount = (count) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
       dispatch({type: GET_LIKES_COUNT, count})
    }  
}

export const GetPosts = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return Axios.get('/api/posts/myPosts')
            .then( (res) => {
                 const data = res.data       
                 dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, data})
             })

    }
}
```

**reducer**

```
const initialState = {
    post: [],
    postError: null,
    posts:[],
    isEditing:false,
    isEditingId:null,
    likes:[],
    someLike:[],
    postId:null
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

    case GET_POSTS:
         return {
             ...state, 
          posts: action.data, // maps posts fine
        }
    case GET_LIKES_COUNT:
        console.log(action.count) 
        return({
            ...state,
            likes: action.count.length
        })
```

**Posts.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostList from './PostList';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {GetPosts} from '../actions/';
const Styles = {
    myPaper:{
      margin: '20px 0px',
      padding:'20px'
    }
    , 
    wrapper:{
      padding:'0px 60px'
    }
}
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    loading: true,
    isEditing: false, 
  }
  async componentWillMount(){
    await this.props.GetPosts();

    const thesePosts = await this.props.myPosts
    const myPosts2 = await thesePosts
    this.setState({
      posts: myPosts2,
      loading:false
    })

    console.log(this.state.posts.Likes);
  }


  render() {
    const {loading} = this.state;
    const { myPosts} = this.props
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/signIn' />);
    }
    if(loading){
      return "loading..."
    }
    return (
      <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
        <h1> Posts </h1>
        <PostList posts={this.state.posts}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
  myPosts: state.post.posts
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, state) => ({
  GetPosts: () => dispatch( GetPosts())
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Posts));
```

**PostItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import moment from 'moment';
import Editable from './Editable';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {UpdatePost, postLike, getCount} from '../actions/';
import Like from './Like';
import Axios from '../Axios';
const Styles = {
    myPaper: {
        margin: '20px 0px',
        padding: '20px'
    },
    button:{
        marginRight:'30px'
    }
}
class PostItem extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            disabled: false,
            myId: 0,
            likes:0
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){

    }
    onUpdate = (id, title) => () => {
        // we need the id so expres knows what post to update, and the title being that only editing the title. 
        if(this.props.myTitle !== null){
            const creds = {
                id, title
            }
            this.props.UpdatePost(creds); 
        }
    }

    render(){
        const {title, id, userId, removePost, createdAt, post_content, username, editForm, isEditing, editChange, myTitle, postUpdate, Likes, clickLike, myLikes} = this.props
        return(
            <div>
                   <Typography variant="h6" component="h3">
                   {/* if else teneray operator */}
                   {isEditing ? (
                          <Editable editField={myTitle ? myTitle : title} editChange={editChange}/>
                   ): (
                       <div>
                           {title}
                       </div>    
                   )}         
                   </Typography>
                   <Typography  component={'span'} variant={'body2'}>
                       {post_content}
                       <h5>by: {username} </h5>
                       {/*  component span cancels out the cant be a decedent of error */}
                       <Typography  component={'span'} variant={'body2'} color="textSecondary">{moment(createdAt).calendar()}</Typography>
                      {/* gets like counts */}
                       <Like like={id} likes={myLikes} /> 
                   </Typography>
                   {!isEditing ? (
                       <Button variant="outlined" type="submit" onClick={editForm(id)}>
                           Edit
                       </Button>
                   ):(     
                       // pass id, and myTitle which as we remember myTitle is the new value when updating the title
                        <div>
                            <Button 
                                disabled={myTitle.length <= 3}
                                variant="outlined" 
                                onClick={this.onUpdate(id, myTitle)}>
                                Update
                            </Button>
                            <Button 
                                variant="outlined" 
                                style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                                onClick={editForm(null)}>
                                Close
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                   )}
                   {!isEditing && (
                    <Button
                        style={{marginLeft: '0.7%'}}
                        variant="outlined"
                        color="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={removePost(id)}>
                        Remove
                    </Button>
                    )}
           </div>
       )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    // myLikes: state.post.likes
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    // pass creds which can be called anything, but i just call it credentials but it should be called something more 
    // specific.
    UpdatePost: (creds) => dispatch(UpdatePost(creds)),
    postLike: (id) => dispatch( postLike(id)),

    // Pass id to the DeletePost functions.
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostItem);
```

Value of `action.count`

[image]

values: 6 
values: 0

[image]

Comment: what is the structure of posts array ?

Comment: Can you please share what's in the `this.props.posts` and what's the value of `action.count`?

Comment: yes once sec please :)

Comment: this.props.posts renders the posts array

Comment: edit(i updated it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're changing the state inside your `render` method.

```
{this.getLikes(post.Likes)}
```

This piece of code leads to an action inside your reducer which then updates the state. That is what redux is all about.

But since react does not allow to change the state while rendering you get your error message. It would eventually lead to an infinite loop when a new state comes up, render didn't finish yet and the new state triggers render again.

What you want to do is put `this.state.likes` at the place of `this.getLikes(post.Likes)` and call the latter inside `componentDidMount`. That way `render` can finish without bein interrupted. On the first call of `render` you have to make sure that `this.state.likes` has a valid value (e.g. `null`) and on the second render `this.state.likes` will have the value of the action you trigger with `this.getLikes(post.Likes)`.

For illustration:

1. `render` (with `this.state.likes = null`)
2. `componentDidMount` gets called
3. redux action
4. `this.state.likes` changes
5. `render` (with `this.state.likes = 6`)

Read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) for detailed information about the lifecycle methods.

Comment: `How would i get post if im not in the posts map loop`

Comment: I updated my answer to show how the lifecycle will affect the state and the render.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up. Going to read it, and implement it Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Let me know if it fixes your issue or if anything is unclear. Just keep in mind to now change the state inside `render` but do that after a user input or at a different point inside the lifecycle.

Comment: "What you want to do is put this.state.likes at the place of this.getLikes(post.Likes) "

Comment: do you mean do this instead this.getLikes(this.state.likes) ?

Comment: No you can not call `this.getLikes` inside `render`. Just put `this.state.likes` there to render what ever value `this.state.likes` has.

Comment: ok,  you  do understand that the like counts are dynamic, it pulls the valuse from json response. I could do Like.length and get the like counts that way but i need to store the like count values within a state to be able to upvote them later on.

Comment: just want to make sure were on the same page, thank you for the help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192426/discussion-between-breakbb-and-mr-patel).